# Delete duplicate rows in MySQL with a condition

Tags: mysql

I have table called "Movies" in a mysql database and it has multiple records for the same movie. The identifier is the "APN" field.

I am trying to delete all the multiple rows but keep the one record which has more complete information.

For example in the below record I would like to delete first two rows but keep the third one as it has more complete information including trailer url.

```
+----+----------+---------+--------+-----------+
Id    APN        Title     Genre    Trailer
+----+----------+---------+--------+------------+
1     1234567    TinTin    NULL      NULL
2     1234567    TinTin    Fiction   NULL
3     1234567    TinTin    Fiction   http://youtube.xyz
+---------------------------------------------------
```

If I use the following query it will just delete the duplicate with lower id.

```
DELETE m1 FROM movies m1
INNER JOIN movies m2 
WHERE m1.id < m2.id AND m1.apn = m2.apn;
```

Can I use the where clause in the query and say delete duplicates rows if the certain columns are null?

Comment: What will you do if you have a trailer for the first row and you don't have the third row? Which one will be deleted, and which one will remain?

Comment: If the trailer field has a value means it has been "touched" and is "good" to keep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though your query works fine in fiddle but you can try below -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0939019959975e7b1d81413c9b7546ee)**

```
DELETE m1 FROM t1 m1
where id not in ( select * from 
                    ( select max(id) from t1 where Trailer is not null group by apn
                    ) A

                )
```

Comment: please run this in the demo : insert into t1 values (1,1234567,'TinTin',null,null),
(2,1234567,'TinTin','Fiction','http://youtube.xyz'),
(3,1234567,'TinTin','Fiction',null)  and when I execute your query it will still show 3rd row and not the 2nd row. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would take a different approach and select those records where the data is most complete by using this query below:

```
select 
max(id), max(apn), max(title), max(genre), max(trailer)
from movies
```

This would give you the row with the most complete answers.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the query:

```
DELETE m1 FROM movies m1
INNER JOIN movies m2 
ON m1.apn = m2.apn
WHERE m1.id != m2.id AND (m1.Trailer IS NULL OR m1.Genre IS NULL OR m1.Title IS NULL)
```

It will delete the rows that don't have trailer or genre or title.